# grails: spring-security and LDAP only

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

I'm having the following error:

```
2011-06-27 17:23:57,241 [http-8080-1] DEBUG authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider  - Processing authentication request for use
r: nvb0343
2011-06-27 17:23:57,241 [http-8080-1] DEBUG search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch  - Searching for user 'xxxxxx', with user search [ s
earchFilter: 'sAMAccountName={0}', searchBase: 'DC=GrupoCGD,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: true ]
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.

2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Cancelling cookie
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to '/fce-test-app/login/authfail?login_erro
r=1'
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as requ
est processing completed
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/login/authfail'; to: '/log
in/authfail'
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Candidate is: '/login/authfail'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2011-06-27 17:23:57,272 [http-8080-1] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 1 of 8 in additional
 filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
```

here's my config:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.derefLink = true    
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider']

//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'XXX\XXX'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'changeme'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://my.ldap.service:389/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true // typically needed for Active Directory
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=XXX,DC=com' 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" // for Active Directory you need this
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false

grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ='dc=*,dc=*'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
```

I've tried gazillions of combinations, but it seems that grails always tries the **rememberMe** service:

**`rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful`**

Comment: It tries to authenticate by each of plugins, one by one, until one of them not authenticate user. Probably there is problem with ldab (not remember me), maybe it can't find suitable user?

Comment: But I'm not configuring the rememberMe plugin/auth service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it. It was a configuration error. Here's a link for posterity: https://gist.github.com/1053710