# Grails Spring LDAP authentication Failed

Tags: grails, spring-ldap

I am trying to get the grails spring ldap to work.No matter what I try,I am not successful in authentication.I am not sure what is causing my error.Here is my config:

```
  grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'cn=root'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = '<value>'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://myserver.com:389'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base ='o=<value>,c=<value'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter = 'sAMAccountName={0}'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
 //grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-1'
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.derefLink = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.mapper.userDetailsClass = 'person'
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['cn', 'displayName'] // extra attributes you want returned
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']

 // role-specific LDAP config
 //grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authenticator.useBind = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase='cn=myUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
```

Logs:

```
2014-04-30 10:24:52,374 [http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider 
2014-04-30 10:24:52,418 [http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: cn=<userid> 2014-04-30 10:24:52,418
[http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - Searching for user 'cn=   <userid>', with user search [ searchFilter: '(uid={0})', searchBase: 'o=<value>,c=<value>', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ] 
2014-04-30 10:24:52,422 [http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'o=<value>,c=<value>', filter = '(uid={0})' 
2014-04-30 10:24:52,422 [http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
2014-04-30 10:24:52,423 [http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie 2014-04-30 10:24:52,423 
[http-bio-8099-exec-8] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/LDAPTest1/login/authfail?login_error=1'
```

Please advise

Java Code:
`

```
public static String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    public static String MY_HOST = "ldap://myserver:389";
    public static String MY_SEARCHBASE = "o=<value>,c=<value>";
    public static String MY_FILTER = "cn=<userid>";
    public static String MGR_DN = "cn=root";
    public static String MGR_PW = "<pwd>";

Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,INITCTX);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,MY_HOST);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,MGR_DN);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,MGR_PW);
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
            constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
//performs the actual search  
//We give it a searchbase, a filter and the contraints containing the scope  
//of the search  
            NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(MY_SEARCHBASE,MY_FILTER,constraints);
```

`

Comment: Do you manage the LDAP or does someone else?  Can you check the logs?  I know for our setup we have do have managerDN='CN=Valu1,OU=Value2,DC=Value3,DC=value4'

Comment: I dont manage LDAP.But our LDAP uses traditional hierarchy starting from root and then c=<value> and then o=value followed by cn

Comment: Can you ask the group/person that manages it what should be in that field?

Comment: thats what is the problem..we dont have anyone managing it..All we have is existing Java application which uses LDAP fro authentication.Using Java,it works.why not grails?I used the same search filter and search base when search using Initial Context.

Comment: Do you have the java source code/config files that makes the connection?  Is that happening in spring or is it custom?

Comment: @BZ please have a look at my working Java code above in post..thanks a lot for ur time

Answer (score 2):

So, [another user had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495963/grails-spring-security-and-ldap-only).

It looks like the main values he changed which also differ from yours are

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
```

Also, your groupSearchBase should be groups, not a specific user. So instead of

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase='cn=myUser'
```

It should probably be more like

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ='DC=Group,DC=com'
```

It also seems like you're using a different search filter in your working Java code than you are in your grails configuration. Your java code has a filter of `"cn=<userid>"`, but your Grails configuration is using the 'sAMAccountName={0}'. I think that sAMAccountName is preferred by Microsoft Active Directory systems, but your LDAP server may be different.

One last thing to check: There are also some things you need to configure for Spring Security Core. Here's a sample from the above link:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.example.SecUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.example.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.example.SecRole'
```

If you're not quite sure what values to use for those settings, check out the Spring Security Plugin docs. There are some required domain classes you'll need to setup.
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: thanks @jonnybot ..So in that case should my search filter be cn={0}?

Comment: I assume so, but ldap query strings are still almost black magic to me. That seems correct, though.

Comment: yea even I dont get that...I tried giving cn={0}..does not work either.I am using a LDAP server that encrypts password using SHA.I am not sure If I have to pass the algorithm.The password in the LDAP begins with {SHA}.I tried every possible combination.It does not seem to work